# hadoop java compiler cannot locate files

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

command submitted:

```
javac -classpath usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-core-0.20.204.0.jar:usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d compiled_programs grep_example/WordCount.java > out 2>error
```

Have reviewed directory, both commons*.jar and core*.jar exist in specified directories.

Errors:

```
grep_example/WordCount.java:4: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
                             ^
grep_example/WordCount.java:5: error: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
                           ^
grep_example/WordCount.java:6: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
                           ^
grep_example/WordCount.java:7: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
                           ^
grep_example/WordCount.java:8: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
                                  ^
grep_example/WordCount.java:9: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
```

What am I doing wrong? New to both Ubuntu and Hadoop.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your classpath is not correct. You `usr/..` in the starting of each library. It should be `/usr/..`

Correct command:

```
javac \
  -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-core-0.20.204.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar \
  -d compiled_programs \
  grep_example/WordCount.java \
  > out 2> error
```